# How do I look for a tag in xml file and find it's grandparent?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml.etree

I have an XML file that I want to parse and look for certain keywords present in it.
The XML file is as below

```
...
...
<OBJECT data="file://localhost//var/tmp/autoclean/derive/TheGeometry//Descartes-TheGeometry.djvu" height="3143" type="image/x.djvu" usemap="Descartes-TheGeometry_0269.djvu" width="2077">
    <PARAM name="PAGE" value="Descartes-TheGeometry_0269.djvu"/>
    <PARAM name="DPI" value="400"/>
    <HIDDENTEXT>
        <PAGECOLUMN>
            <REGION>
                <PARAGRAPH>
                    <LINE>
                        <WORD coords="653,237,937,202,236">CATALOGUE</WORD>
                        <WORD coords="962,238,1022,205,237">OF</WORD>
                        <WORD coords="1045,240,1208,205,238">DOVER</WORD>
                        <WORD coords="1231,239,1389,205,238">BOOKS</WORD>
                    </LINE>
                    ...
                </PARAGRAPH>
                ...
                ...
    <HIDDENTEXT>
</OBJECT>
...
...
```

Now I wish to search for a keyword in the `<WORD>` tag and check value attribute of the first `<PARAM>` tag lying corresponding to the immediate parent `<OBJECT>` .
For example, let's say I searched for a keyword `BOOKS` then I want to get the value from this tag`<PARAM name="PAGE" value="Descartes-TheGeometry_0269.djvu"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import lxml.html as lh
books = """[your code]"""
doc = lh.fromstring(books)
vals = doc.xpath('//object/param[following-sibling::hiddentext//word="books"][1]/@value')
for val in vals:
    print(val)
```

Output:

```
descartes-thegeometry_0269.djvu
```